# Custom format string

Tags: c#, string, format, message, mq

I am looking for some generic solution, so that I can generate the string. Like I want first 10 characters to be reserved for id, next 20 characters needs to reserved for name etc. but this character length my change. This requirement is for ibm mq message,.
E.g.: if my id is 001, name is namexxxx and age 25 then my final string should look like:

```
001       namexxxx            25
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `String.PadRight` you can achieve that. You can also pass these as parameters to a method, or read them from a configuration file or database:

```
Console.WriteLine(id.PadRight(10) + name.PadRight(20) + age.PadRight(5));
```

Another way would be to use `String.Format` but this one is a bit messier to parametrize:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0,-10}{1,-20}{2,-5}", id, name, age));
```

Output in both cases:

```
001       namexxxx            25
```

Comment: @user1739969 Please mark this answer as accepted if you find it helpful. If you don't know how, it is a simple single step described here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235